# Using HTML property as css selector

Tags: html, css

The common practice in styling html using CSS is using id or class for selector. What is the reason for not using html property as selector?

Using CSS

```css
.success {
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input class="success"/>
```

vs Using HTML Property

```css
input[success] {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input success />
```

Comment: probably because [attr] came later in the specification and because class can take more than 1 single  value ? . you even have data-attributes if both do not suits your needs ;)

Comment: Both are common.

Answer (score 2):

The id attribute uniquely identifies an element in the page … and not just for CSS.

The class attribute provides a list of arbitrary categories that you assign to the element … and not just for CSS.

Making up your own attributes results in invalid HTML, right up until the point where the language changes to add a new one which clashes with the one you made up resulting in expected behaviour being applied to your element by browsers.

Comment: There's no reason not to use custom HTML attributes, HTML5 allows these. Look at Bootstrap and Foundation as frameworks that religiously use custom HTML attributes.

Comment: @joshwcorbett — There's a good reason not to use custom HTML attributes, I described it in the last paragraph of this answer. Bootstrap doesn't use custom attributes, it does use a lot of different classes. I've never looked at Foundation … but having skimmed a random Foundation template I see lots of classes and no custom attributes.

Comment: These frameworks use custom attributes for DOM manipulation: https://get.foundation/sites/docs/slider.html

Comment: @joshwcorbett — Oh, `data-` attributes. That isn't the same as what the question proposed. And they don't use them purely as CSS targets.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice, you *should* use the HTML selector as much as possible. This makes the code more manageable and understandable to humans. There are also performance benefits (though that's less of an issue these days).

That said, there are plenty of times when it NOT advantageous to use the HTML selector. Your example has a state attribute but not all elements do. How will you display text differently in your `div` when it's a warning instead of contextual information? There's no default attribute for that.

It's also much easier to toggle classes than it is to set attributes with something like Javascript.

Finally, you can account for edge cases that would require very convoluted HTML selectors `li > li:nth-child(11)` when you could just add a class `.special`. This is extra true when your li's are dynamic and you no longer want to highlight the 11th one...

---

To answer your question. Nothing's stopping people. But I'm personally going to write code in the easiest possible way that solves my problem. I assume I'm very "normal" in that aspect and others have similar reasons.